# Netflix on Firefox: "The WidevineCdm plugin has crashed"

Tags: firefox, ppa, netflix, drm

I installed Firefox from `ppa:mozillateam/ppa` but Netflix is not working and gives the error: "The WidevineCdm plugin has crashed".

I tried to use another user (a new user), I tried to disable and enable again drm, I tried it with no extensions, I tried to reinstall Firefox and install `libavcodec-extra` as suggested in other threads but nothing, always the same error.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and Firefox version is 102.0.1 (64-bit).

Using the Snap version is not an option for me, I would rather change OS than using Firefox as a Snap, so I'm looking for a way to have a working Firefox installed with a `.deb`.

#### Edit:

Apparently the problem is related only to this version of Firefox. Firefox-ESR version 91.11.0 installed from the same ppa works perfectly, I think I will use this until the other is fixed.

Comment: I got the same error on PlutoTV but it didn't stop me from watching. However, it *did* make it impossible to use my Crave.ca subscription on Firefox. (KDE Neon here, on an Ubuntu 22.04 base and a Neon-packaged version of Firefox.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download it from the official site [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#product-desktop-release)
and after that extract the tar and to run go into the Firefox directory and run the Firefox executable to make sure to works

- then move the Firefox folder to `~/.local/lib` (note if it does not exist, make it)
- make a symlink with this `mkdir -p ~/.local/bin/ ; ln -s ~/.local/lib/firefox/firefox ~/.local/bin/firefox`
- after that run this `sudo sed -i 's/Exec=firefox/Exec=~\/.local\/bin\/firefox/g'  /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`

Comment: It works, confirming there is something wrong with mozillateam repository. It's a shame that I have to update it manually with this setup. Do you know if there is a way to get it from another repository?

Comment: no firefox has a auto updater in it like windows

Answer (score 15):

I am not really fond of snap version of Firefox, so I am also using `ppa:mozillateam/ppa` on Ubuntu 22.10 and the problem really is related to AppArmor's Firefox config file.

I also edited `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox` but the recommended line by @skoruppa didn´t do the trick. Use this instead:

1. bellow the line:
   `# per-user firefox configuration`
2. write:
   `owner @{HOME}/.{firefox,mozilla}/**/gmp-widevinecdm/**/libwidevinecdm.so m,`
3. After that, you can reboot your computer (or reload AppArmor's rules with `apparmor_parser --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox`).

Comment: This does not depend of snap nor ppa.  The problem is the AppArmor config.

Comment: The linux version per se does not matter as the bum config file gets picked up by several levels and flavors.  Don't know if the FIreFox people contributed to the AppArmor file being propagated through the universe or if the FF people review install FF materials given out to the world, but would opening a problem with Mozilla help?  Or AppArmor?

Answer (score 9):

Just occurred the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04 with Firefox from the official PPA. After googling for a bit I found out that the issue is caused by AppArmor which does not let to run Widevin plugin from your home directory - this was already reported 4 years ago (!) here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1777070

To fix the issue you need to edit the `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox` file
and add

```
owner @{HOME}/.{firefox,mozilla}/**/gmp-widevinecdm/*/lib*so m,
```

to the `# per-user firefox configuration` section.

After that, you can reboot your computer (or reload AppArmor's rules with `apparmor_parser --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox`) and everything will be working just fine :)

I hope this will helpful to someone else

Comment: The command below worked for me, based on Skoruppa's link. owner @{HOME}/.{firefox,mozilla}/**/gmp-widevinecdm/*/lib*so m,

Comment: Works like a charm on Firefox 112.0.1. Thanks for this!

Comment: Thanks for identifying this as an AppArmor issue. It wasn't obvious, to say the least. I've *got* to learn to debug AppArmor issues, which I've put off way too long.